# Java Annotations in narrow scope

Tags: java, annotations, code-organization

If we have an annotation that is used to set certain Class-specific **Constants**, declared this way:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Tooltip {
  String value();
}
```

Used like so:

```
package applicationroot

@Tooltip("createCubeTool.tipText")
public class CreateCubeTool extends EditingTool
{
}
```

with this in the supertype:

```
public abstract class EditingTool
{
  public String getToolTipText()
  {
    //Don't worry about this, other than that it requires a custom value Per Concrete class.
    return null == tooltip ? null : Translate.text(tooltip.value());
  }
}
```

*Where* should the annotation be declared?

Leaving aside questions regarding the overall structure of the project, it occurred to me that this particular annotation is only useful in subclasses of the scope of the `ModelingTool` type. Does it make sense to declare it in an entirely separate package, `package applicationroot.tool.annotations;` as one contributor suggested, or would it be better declared as a member of the `ModelingTool` type that uses it?

All references that I have found so far talk about *how* to declare a custom annotation, but not where they fit into a project's overall structure.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if the `text` is variable for some reasons, for example it needs to be formatted or transformed before output, declaring it as an instance member maybe the better idea.

On the contrary, a decided **CONSTANT** can be defined in the meta info of an annotation. Remarkably, you have to use *reflection* to get the meta info which may degrade performance. The *reflection* brings a deep call stack.

In this case, I don't think it's worth using annotation. You have little expected benefit from the refactor, except an ostensibly elegant code.

Comment: The text, as written at the class level, is a Key into our translation mapping system, and is defined uniquely per concrete type. (Thus the calls to `Translate()`)

Comment: BTW, while I appreciate the thoughts, and will consider them, they're somewhat orthogonal to my question. I see how the original question might have had some data overload. I've edited to hopefully make it more clear what I am asking.